# Arduino: find the peak and troughs in sensor data

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to poll an accelerometer every *x* ms on 3 axiz, and trying to figure out how to determine the peaks and troughs of the readings I get.

Ideally, I wouldn't want to collect a whole bunch of data before I can start counting the peaks - maybe every 10 minutes at most if data collection is first required. The peaks should also only be counted if the absolute value of the peak is within an acceptable "distance" of the average set of peaks - to prevent a very small peak from being counted...

I would appreciate any pointers wrt doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with calculation of standard deviation and count peaks which deviates more than a specified level.

[Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation//)

Comment: Thanks Espen, this *might* work with a bit of additional elbow grease applied - my samples may be rather closely spaced, so I will have to build in a sub-routine to "cluster" the peak values and only take the maximum, and also only one maximum should there be more than one value for the maximum. Still hoping for some code snippets from someone who have done this before... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your signal looks like.  I solved a similar problem with a sinusoidal signal using an used a IIR filter on the signal to smooth out the noise and prevent false peaks.

You might try something like this:

```
int signalPin = 3;     // accel connected to pin 3
float signal;
float gain = 0.1;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(signalPin, INPUT);
  signal = analogRead(signalPin);  // get initial reading
}

void loop()
{
  // allow a new reading of the accel to slightly change the signal (depending on the value of gain)
  signal += (analogRead(signalPin)*gain - signal);  // IIR filter
}
```

You will probably also want to use the map function to adjust the value obtained from analogRead, as well as use int or long instead of float if you're worried about efficiency.

Now you can use a strategy like the following:
Read a new value from the accel (checking if a new value is higher than the previous and if so, save it as the new max.  When they stop increasing, that is your max value.  You can require N number of samples within a certain threshold to verify you are at the flat top of the peak.  Hopefully, this gets you started.